# Use KeycloakOwinAuthentication to authorize asp.net web api 2 services

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, keycloak

I want to use this unmaintained [project](https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication) in order to authorize the services of my web api because it is mandatory for us to use Keycloak.

It has been quite easy to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication/wiki/ASP.NET-MVC-Tutorial) and making it work in my web api but I cannot found any example of using tokens instead of interactive login. 
The web api will receive with the http request an authorization header of our already logged client and the target is to securize the services and authorize them based on some roles.

I've perform some changes in Startup.cs - Configuration method:

```
ConfigureAuth(app);
app.UseKeycloakAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // App-Specific Settings
            ClientId = "demo-app", // *Required*
            ClientSecret = "ssshhhh", // If using public authentication, delete this line
            VirtualDirectory = "", // Set this if you use a virtual directory when deploying to IIS

            // Instance-Specific Settings
            Realm = "PruebaRealm", // Don't change this unless told to do so
            KeycloakUrl = "http://example.com/auth", // Enter your Keycloak URL here

            // Template-Specific Settings
            EnableWebApiMode = true,
            AuthenticationType = "KeycloakOwinAuthenticationSample_keycloak_auth", // Unique identifier for the auth middleware
        });
```

And I've added the authorization attribute to the htttp method:

```
[Authorize]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{    
    PrivilegeProvider pPrivileges = new PrivilegeProvider();
    var searchResults = pPrivileges.GetPrivilege();
    if (searchResults == null)
        return NotFound();
    return Ok(searchResults);
    }
```

When I perform the request including the authorization header

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
Authorization: bearer thisisanexamplethisisanexamplethisisanexample....
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:49729
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:4200/privilegios
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36
```

I always receive:

```
Access Unauthorized: Requires valid bearer token authorization header
```

Can anyone give me an advice to achieve this goal?
I'm thinking about creating my own adapter using owin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create a default authentication scheme for it to work. Authorize attribute unable to handle the claims in your case.